# Pegar todas as imagens de um sub-diretório, em exceção de uma pasta

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

Eu estou pegando todas as fotos de um diretório e seus subsequentes, mas eu não gostaria que fosse a pasta "Backup", como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
string[] Arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(PathEx, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Eu estava pensando em usar o `IndexOf()`, mas eu penso que isso seria uma má otimização, pois não seria mais fácil tirá-los do que apenas verificar se está na pasta certa ou errada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o mais fácil é usar LINQ.

```
var arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => !f.Contains("Backup")).ToArray();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/DirectoryFilter.cs).

O [`ToArray()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToArray__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) pode não ser necessário aí dependendo do que for fazer em seguida.

Tem um problema aí. Se o arquivo ou outra parte do caminho tiver a palavra "Backup", vai filtrar. Se isso é inadequado teria que ver o critério de onde especificamente no caminho pode ter o "Backup" para considerar no filtro.