# Como pegar apenas uma parte do nome de um diretório?

Tags: c#

Olá,

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para localizar um arquivo em um diretório e salvar no banco, bem como salvar tbm o PATH.
Porém eu preciso salvar apenas o nome dos diretórios que ele se encontra, sem ser o diretório completo.

Por exemplo: Os arquivos ficam por padrão sempre na pasta C:\ARQUIVOS\ {0} \ {1} \ {2}

Eu preciso pegar apenas o nome das pastas descritas em {0}, {1}, {2}.

Consegui fazer isso, mas apenas pegando o path inteiro:

```
static void BuscaRecursivaDiretorios(string caminho)
    {
        DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo(caminho);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo objSubDir in objDir.GetDirectories())
        {
            BuscaRecursivaDiretorios(objSubDir.FullName);
        }

        foreach (FileInfo objFile in objDir.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(objFile.FullName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uma forma seria o que já foi respondido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35400/101.

Pode ser que o que te ajude mais é: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208381/101.

Talvez nem queira separar tudo e só pegar um deles específico como em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243891/101.

Ou ainda só saber se tem um nome nele https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260115/101

Comment: Os exemplos não ficaram claro pra mim. Mas de qualquer forma obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quebrei a cabeça por muito tempo pra fazer isso, pois estava tentando seguir a linha de raciocínio dos posts apresentados.
Mas de nada serviu. Eis que em fim consegui a solução.

```
item.Replace(@"C:\Arquivos", "");
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o valor que quero localizar e o segundo o que quero substituir.